# Read multiple files to run analysis on each file and store them in a file in r studio

Tags: r, loops, csv, for-loop, dataframe

I have 6 folders and each is containing 2200 CSV files, I know how to read them all in a file and create a joint dataset, but the problem is I need to apply statistical functions on each file and then store those values(getting from each file with the name of that file) into another file. As I have to analyze only 5th and 6th column of each file and compute Standard dev, Mean, Variance, Skewness and kurtosis of these columns and from each file.
then my dataset will be the file of having the name of all files in the first column, Std dev as second, mean as third, and so on.

I am not been able to analyze(find statistical parameters of 5th & 6th column) single-2 file through a loop. It would be very helpful to me if somebody can help me out from this.

Comment: So what's the actual problem? Just use something like `lapply(list_of_files, function(x) { df <- read.csv(x)[, 5:6]; # Calculate summary stats and store in output file })`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on my comment above here is a minimal reproducible example.

When you read in your CSV files you should get a list of `data.frame`s. Since you don't provide sample data (or a reproducible minimal example), let's generate a `list` of 2 `data.frame`s as sample data.

```
set.seed(2017)
lst <- replicate(2, data.frame(x1 = rnorm(10), x2 = rnorm(10), x3 = rnorm(10)), simplify = F)
```

We now define a function that calculates the desired summary statistics. The R package `moments` provides functions to calculate skewness and kurtosis.

```
library(moments)
calc.sum.stats <- function(x) c(
    Std.Dev = sd(x),
    Mean = mean(x),
    Var = var(x),
    Skew = skewness(x),
    Kur = kurtosis(x))
```

We now use `lapply` to loop through the `list` of `data.frame`s and apply `calc.sum.stats` to columns 2 and 3 of every `data.frame`. We store the output in a new `list`; alternatively you can write the output to a new file.

```
lst.out <- lapply(lst, function(x) sapply(x[, 2:3], calc.sum.stats))
lst.out
#[[1]]
#                 x2          x3
#Std.Dev 1.096376114  0.99908334
#Mean    0.001866057 -0.01558136
#Var     1.202040583  0.99816751
#Skew    0.195200696  0.25926229
#Kur     1.545595827  2.75636328
#
#[[2]]
#                 x2          x3
#Std.Dev  0.89417725  1.19341132
#Mean     0.11378986 -0.01771822
#Var      0.79955296  1.42423058
#Skew    -0.05177617  0.08220936
#Kur      1.45491801  1.72107415
```